# ¿Cómo puedo abrir y visualizar archivos almacenados en un servidor web (IIS) desde un cliente?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

He creado un pequeño sistema web (en asp.net y sql server) que permite compartir y abrir los  archivos compartidos en modo solo lectura, los almaceno en una carpeta y guardo la dirección (ubicación y nombre) en la base de datos. De manera local (en el entorno de desarrollo) funciona perfectamente (compartir y abrir archivos) pero cuando lo monto en el servidor y abro el sistema en otra PC ya no puedo abrir los archivos, no me arroja ningún tipo de error, simplemente no hace nada.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes,  lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:
la ruta del archivo en la base de datos debe quedarte conformada de la siguiente manera:

/web/Content/Uploads/archivo.doc

/Nombre de la Aplicación/Content/Carpeta de Archivos/el archivo

En el Modelo Ruta es de tipo string.

En el Controlador para guardar la ruta del archivo:

```
 public ActionResult Create(Archivo archivo, HttpPostedFileBase documento)
    {

        archivo.Ruta = "/web/Content/Uploads/documento.FileName;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            documento.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(archivo.Ruta));
            db.Archivos.Add(archivo);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["exito"] = "La información se ha insertado correctamente.";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["error"] = "No se ha podido insertar la información.";
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(logTransp);
    }
```

En la vista para llamar el documento puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Documentos
                    </th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>                            
                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="@Url.Content(item.Ruta)"> <span> Descargar</span></a>
                       </td>                           
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```